# Cannot install node modules when deploying Azure App Service

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, npm, deployment

I have a Node.js *App Service* in Azure which I created following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-nodejs) and then adding some more stuff. My app consists in one file:

```
var http = require("http");
//var mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient; // !!!THIS LINE!!!

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end('Hello World\n');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
server.listen(port);
```

Keep in mind the highlighted line for later.

#### Deployment

Since I am using *MongoDB*, I have this line in my `package.config`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "mongodb": "^3.0.1"
}
```

Azure must run `npm install` when deploying. So, following the [Azure Guidelines for deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps), I have added a `.deployment` file:

```
[config]
command = bash deploy.sh
```

Note that my app is **hosted on Linux**. File `deploy.sh` takes care of running the command for installing npm deps:

```
if [ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET/package.json" ]; then
  echo Installing NuGetpackages.
  cd "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
  eval $NPM_CMD install --production
  exitWithMessageOnError "npm failed"
  cd - > /dev/null
fi
```

#### The problem

If I keep that line commented, everything is fine. But if I uncomment it, then deployment fails. **Locally it works on my box!**, but not in the cloud. When inspecting deployment logs, I can see that the `npm install` command is executed:

```
Command: bash deploy.sh
Handling node.js deployment.
Handling KuduSync.
Kudu sync from: '/home/site/repository' to: '/home/site/wwwroot'
Ignoring: .deployment
Copying file: '.gitignore'
Copying file: 'LICENSE'
Copying file: 'README.md'
Ignoring: deploy.sh
Copying file: 'package.json'
Copying file: 'process.json'
Deleting file: 'deploy.cmd'
Ignoring: .git
Copying file: 'src/db.js'
Copying file: 'src/index.js'
Copying file: 'src/settings.json'
Copying file: 'src/data/info.js'
Copying file: 'src/data/page.js'
Detecting node version spec...
Using package.json engines.node value: >=6.9.1
Node.js versions available on the platform are: 4.4.7, 4.5.0, 6.2.2, 6.6.0, 6.9.3, 6.10.3, 6.11.0, 8.0.0, 8.1.0.
Resolved to version 8.1.0
Detecting npm version spec...
Using default for node 8.1.0: 5.0.3
NPM versions available on the platform are: 2.15.8, 2.15.9, 3.9.5, 3.10.3, 3.10.10, 5.0.3.
Resolved to version 5.0.3
Installing NuGet packages.
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /usr/bin/node but npm is using /opt/nodejs/8.1.0/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
up to date in 2.885s
myuser-web-srv@0.1.0 /home/site/repository
npm ERR! missing: mongodb@^3.0.1, required by myuser-web-srv@0.1.0
`-- UNMET DEPENDENCY mongodb@^3.0.1
```

But `mongodb` does not get installed. Why?.

#### Using KUDU

If I log in the Kudu tools for my app service and open a Bash session, and run `npm install --production` under `wwwroot`, then `mongodb` is successfully installed :(

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question I know but I ended up here and wanna share that you can put a setting in app service configuration saying SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true which seem to be needed in some cases (when kudu detects its node it wont do npm install without this setting).

Comment: I did your solution. I get this now: tar (child): node_modules.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-nodejs) to create my Node.js web app in Azure App Service on Linux. Azure App Service understands **package.json** and **npm-shrinkwrap.json** files and can install modules based on entries in these files. I just created the following `package.json` file and committed it to my bitbucket repository.

**My repository:**

[image]

**package.json:**

```
{
    "name": "app-service-hello-world",
    "description": "Simple Hello World Node.js sample for Azure App Service",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "license": "MIT",
    "author": "Bruce Chen",
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=6.9.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "mongodb": "^3.0.1"
    }
}
```

Then, I checked the deployment traces under the "DEPLOYMENT > Deployment options" section of my azure web app via Azure Portal and retrieved the **Running deployment command** activity as follows:

[image]

Using [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/), I found the dependencies have been successfully installed as follows:

[image]

Moreover, my deployment script could automatically generate successfully. I do not need to [Custom Deployment Script](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script).

Comment: I have updated my question with more info. But in my case, your exact procedure is not working :(

Comment: Have you tried to use KUDU and manually execute `npm install --production` under the `/home/site/wwwroot` directory to narrow this issue.

Comment: If I do that, it installs `mongodb`... strange. Why?

Comment: These app services are notorious for failing npm installs.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, node_modules are installed thro kudo but once I try to run the app from azure portal, the node_modules disappears!!!!!