# What is process.json file in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

It seems to be basic for you to answer but still I couldn't able to find out what is **process.json** file in **Node.js** and what it does, is that any file exists in **Node.js** ?

I went through one of the question on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48043598/cannot-install-node-modules-when-deploying-azure-app-service) in which **process.json** file is showing when installing npm modules.

Can you please answer me about the same that will be really helpful ?

Comment: Can someone answer this please ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**process.json** is used for **PM2** module of **Node.js** which is a General Purpose Process Manager and a Production Runtime for **Node.js** apps with a built-in Load Balancer.

PM2 empowers process management workflow.

**Key features of PM2 are:**

1. Simple and efficient process management (start/stop/restart/delete/show/monit)
2. Keep your application ALWAYS ONLINE with auto restarts and init system script generation
3. Clusterize Node.js Applications without code change to increase performance and reliability
4. Hot Reload Node.js Applications without extra configuration

***Starting an application in production mode can be done using this simple command***

```
$ pm2 start app.js
```

To dive into more details for **process.json**, you can refer [this](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#json-format)